# Data format that looks like JSON, but isn't. Can you help identify it?

Tags: xml, json, data-structures

I have no friggin' clue what this data format is called. Do you recognize it?

http://pastebin.me/ced13687cf12fb85b334a5960a4cf985

It's JSON-esque, but obviously not JSON. We can thank Google for blessing us with this little enigma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the input for my command line arguments parsing library ;]